# Load from Properties.Settings to ArrayList?

Tags: c#, arraylist, settings.settings

Here is the settings file that is leftover from saving. (Saving the properties works correctly.)

```
<setting name="AlarmList" serializeAs="Xml">
<value>
    <ArrayOfAnyType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <anyType xsi:type="ArrayOfAnyType">
            <anyType xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2009-12-04T02:00:00</anyType>
            <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">string1</anyType>
            <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">string2</anyType>
        </anyType>
        <anyType xsi:type="ArrayOfAnyType">
            <anyType xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2009-12-04T03:00:00</anyType>
            <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">string1</anyType>
            <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">string2</anyType>
        </anyType>
    </ArrayOfAnyType>
</value>
```

How can I load this back into the app using ArrayList?
This is how I saved it.

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.Add(SetAlarm.Value);
list.Add("string1");
list.Add("string2");
Settings.AlarmList2.Add(list);
Settings.Save();
```

Anyone know how I can use this to load the data from the settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but I think you can do:

```
ArrayList all = Settings.AlarmList2;
foreach (ArrayList items in all) {
     // items [0] -> DateTime
     // items [1] -> string1
     // items [2] -> string2
}
```